# error LGHT0311 while including License.rtf file in Wix Toolset Application

Tags: windows, wix, installation

I am using WIX Toolset to create MSI Application and I want to provide my own License file to display during the license Agreement on License Agreement Dialog.
I created a new document in word-pad and saved it with .rtf extension. Whatever the content of document wix is not getting build and the error which comes is error LGHT0311.

```
C:\agent\_work\8\s\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs(27,0): error LGHT0311: A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified database code page '1252'. Either change these characters to ones that exist in the database's code page, or update the database's code page by modifying one of the following attributes: Product/@Codepage, Module/@Codepage, Patch/@Codepage, PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.


Note:- LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs(27,0) contains this line  <Text SourceFile="!(wix.WixUILicenseRtf=$(var.licenseRtf))" />
```

I have tried adding Codepage value as 1252 in Product tag and SummaryCodepage in Package Tag. I have tried even by putting only one character in License file but still getting same error.

Please help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your license with WordPad and save it with *.rtf extension.
I was creating the license with Microsoft Office Word, and then saving with *.rtf extension, which was giving error like above.